# spawn git ENOENT in Application generation Jhipster

Tags: jhipster

When tried to generate  using https://start.jhipster.tech/generate-application

Show me error :

```
 GitError:GitError: Error: 

spawn git ENOENT
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
        at Object.action (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/simple-git/src/lib/plugins/error-detection.plugin.js:30:33)
        at PluginStore.exec (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/simple-git/src/lib/plugins/plugin-store.js:21:33)
        at /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/simple-git/src/lib/runners/git-executor-chain.js:95:45
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at GitExecutorChain.handleTaskData (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/simple-git/src/lib/runners/git-executor-chain.js:93:16)
        at GitExecutorChain.<anonymous> (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/simple-git/src/lib/runners/git-executor-chain.js:77:46)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at fulfilled (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/simple-git/src/lib/runners/git-executor-chain.js:5:58) {
      task: {
        commands: [ 'rev-parse', '--is-inside-work-tree' ],
        format: 'utf-8',
        onError: [Function: onError],
        parser: [Function: parser]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the deployment (missing git). It is rolled out and should be fixed now https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/16544